# Problem about expected value in this game

Tags: probability, expected-value

I have this statement:

> A box contains 4 socks, brown, yellow, green and purple. The game
>   consists of extracting one by one the socks without replacement. If
>   the first one comes out coffee player wins $500$, if the second sock
>   goes coffee the player wins $200$, if in none of the previous attempts
>   is removed the coffee colored sock, loses $400$, What is the expected
>   value in this game?

My attempt:

The probability that I get the brown sock on the first extraction is: $1/4$

Now, if in the first extraction I did not obtain the coffee, then I will have 3 remaining socks in the second extraction, of which $1$ is coffee, so the probability of obtaining it in the second extraction is: $1/3$

And the probabilty of loss is equal to: loss in the first and lost in the second, that is: $3/4  * 2/3 = 1/2$

Therefore, $E(X) = 500/4 +200/3 -400/2 = -25/3$, but the correct answer must be $-25$ and i don't know what is wrong with my development. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The probability of getting the brown on the second extraction is not $\frac{1}{3}$, but rather $\frac{3}{4}\times\frac{1}{3}$, as you first have to miss to draw it. That should fix your problem.

Comment: So, the probability is: Losing in the first and winning in the second?

Comment: I’m saying you just need to modify your $E(X)$ to reflect this occurrence. Your first probability and third are good, your second is the one that’s off. That’s because you forgot to take into account the action that preceded it. If you calculate the EV with $3/4\times1/3$ instead of just $1/3$, you’ll find that you get $-25$ as desired.

Comment: Another way of thinking about it is to realize that your total probabilities added up to more than $1$, which isn’t possible.